# Conditional injection of ViewModel into ViewController using Swinject

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swinject

I'm using `Swinject` to inject dependencies and so far its been working great. But now I've got a scenario in which I have a `ViewController` that has a dependency on its `ViewModel`. `ViewModel` conforms to `ViewModeling` protocol and can be one of two types (both conforms to the same protocol, but has profoundly a different behaviour).

I'm trying to figure out **how can I inject the right `ViewModel`** (a decision that has to be made on runtime)?

I've noticed I can use the `Container` to register each of the `ViewModel` by `name` and then use the `name` to distinguish which `ViewModel` should be injected, which at first seems like a good solution - until I found out I can't instantiate the `ViewController` with the name (or maybe I've missed it?)

I've also thought about exposing a property on my `DependencyInjector` class which will be use to manually inject the right `ViewModel` - though it feels to me that this approach totally miss the point of having automatic dependency injection solution, and also force me to dirt the dependency injector with some business logic code.

Any help or thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using SwinjectStoryboard for view controllers? If so, you can use `swinjectRegistrationName` attribute in storyboard: https://github.com/Swinject/SwinjectStoryboard#registration-with-name

Comment: I am using `SwinjectStoryboard`, but your suggestion means I'll have to keep two duplicated `ViewController`s and each one will have a different name - which seems like an issue for me (every change in the `ViewController` would mean I'll have to remember to update both copies)

Answer (score 2):

One way to not mix DI with application logic would be some kind of "proxy" view model which would implement logic for distinguishing between two variants. You could implement it with different interface, e.g.

```
protocol ViewModelProxy {
    var viewModel: ViewModel { get }
}
```

or more transparently:

```
protocol ViewModel {
    func foo()
}

class ViewModelProxy: ViewModel {
    private let viewModel1: ViewModel
    private let viewModel2: ViewModel

    private var viewModel: ViewModel {
        if shouldUseViewModel1 {
            return viewModel1
        } else {
            return viewModel2
        }
    }

    func foo() {
        viewModel.foo()
    }
}
```

Then you could always inject `ViewModelProxy` to the view controller.